# Crear tablero ajedrez con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Quiero crear un tablero de ajedrez en javascript, me piden que cada cuadro sea de un tamaño establecido por el usuario, lo unico que he conseguido es el tamaño de los cuadros, y un input donde pongo la cantidad de cuadros que quiero, pero no es asi como se formaria el tablero, debo de quitar la cantidad de cuadro que quiero, y que cuando pulse el boton al establecer el tamaño de los cuadros se genere el tablero entero.
Aqui el codigo que llevo :

```
  function generartablero(){
var cantidad=document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
var alto=document.getElementById('alto').value;
var ancho=document.getElementById('ancho').value;
document.getElementById('cuadros').innerHTML='';

for (var i=0;i<cantidad;i++){
    if(i%2==0){
        document.getElementById('cuadros').innerHTML+='<div id="cuadros" style="border:solid 1px;width:'+ alto +'px;height:' + ancho +'px;background-color:gray;float:left;"><div>';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('cuadros').innerHTML+='<div id="cuadros" style="border:solid 1px;width:'+ alto +'px;height:' + ancho +'px;background-color:black;float:left;"><div>';

    }
    }
}
```

y aqui el cuerpo

```
    Cantidad de cuadros a generar : <input type="text" id="cantidad">
<br>
Altura de cuadro : <input type="text" id="alto">
<br>
Anchura de cuadro : <input type="text" id="ancho">
<br>
<input type="button" value="Generar" onclick="generartablero()">
<br>
<div id="cuadros"></div>
```

solo me falta modoficar la funcion para que se genere el tablero con los 64 cuadros. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], si no públicas tu código entonces tú pregunta luce amplia y casi basada en opiniones lo cual generaría su su cierre

Comment: acabo de editar el post con mi codigo, gracias!

Comment: Podrías apoyarte en esta librería: https://chessboardjs.com/ hace un tiempo (bastante) la utilicé y es muy buena y fácil de utilizar.

Comment: No se si esté incumpliendo las normas del sitio, pero si te sirve, te comparto el repositorio del ejemplo que hice de la librería (con .Net): https://github.com/CamiloBernal/softChessInc

Comment: hola @CamiloBernal gracias por responder, pero no necesito un ajedrez en si, solo generar un tablero, con 64 cuadros.

Comment: Ok. Pero no me queda claro si el usuario puede poner "cantidad", porque hablas de 64 posiciones?.

Comment: @CamiloBernal lo de "cantidad" es algo que he agregado yo para poder generar los cuadros que yo quiera, solo para poder verlo, pero no lo necesito, eso puedo quitarlo, lo que necesito es que dandole al boton, me genere un tablero con 64 cuadros y como si fuese el de un ajedrez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fíjate que en un tablero de ajedrez, las casillas blancas de las filas impares coinciden con las columnas impares y las de las filas pares coinciden con las columnas pares, es decir:

```
Casillas blancas: (columna % 2 == fila % 2)
Casillas negras: (columna % 2 != fila % 2)
```

Basado en tu código, cambia eso en el `IF`, además de hacer que el contenedor tenga un ancho fijo para 8 casillas, un par de correcciones más en el código y tendrás tu tablero:

```js
  function generartablero(){
var cantidad=64;//document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
var alto=document.getElementById('alto').value;
var ancho=document.getElementById('ancho').value;
document.getElementById('cuadros').innerHTML='';
document.getElementById('cuadros').style.width = ((2 + parseInt(ancho)) * 8) + "px";

for (var i=0;i<cantidad;i++){
    if(Math.floor(i/8)%2 == i%2){
        document.getElementById('cuadros').innerHTML+='<div id="cuadros" style="border:solid 1px;width:'+ ancho +'px;height:' + alto +'px;background-color:gray;float:left;"><div>';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('cuadros').innerHTML+='<div id="cuadros" style="border:solid 1px;width:'+ ancho +'px;height:' + alto +'px;background-color:black;float:left;"><div>';

    }
    }
}
```

```css
#cuadros {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>Alto: <input type="text" id="alto"/></div>
<div>Ancho: <input type="text" id="ancho"/></div>
<div><button onclick="generartablero()">Generar</button></div>
<div id="cuadros"></div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora he entendido lo que me faltaba, o en lo que me equivocaba.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta @Vlady. Solo le agregaría que se debe evitar duplicar los Id de los elementos.