# Creando tablero de ajedrez

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo un curso de javascript, y como practica me han pedido crear un tablero de ajedrez utilizando funciones. Apenas llevo 2 semanas con el curso por lo que no tengo mucha idea de por donde empezar. El profesor realizo varios ejercicios y dijo que servirian de base, pero utilizando lo que he visto solo logro crear esto, pero no me sirve de nada. He pensado que a lo mejor tengo que utilizar condicionales o un bucle pero no se por donde empezar la verdad. Os dejo el codigo a ver si me podeis echar una mano.

```
    <script>

        function chess(pBoardNumber, pBoardWidth) {

        document.write('<div "width: ' + pBoardNumber + ' px; height: ' + pBoardWidth + 'px; style= background-color: black"></div>');
            

        }

        function chess(pBoardNumber, pBoardWidth) {

        document.write('<div "width: ' + pBoardNumber + ' px; height: ' + pBoardWidth + 'px; style= background-color: white"></div>');
    

        }


        function chess(pBoardNumber, pBoardWidth) {

        document.write('<div "width: ' + pBoardNumber + ' px; height: ' + pBoardWidth + 'px; style= background-color: black"></div>');
    

        }   



        var width = prompt("Dime un ancho")
        var columns = prompt("Dime un numero de casillas")

        


    </script>
```

Comment: Y que hace el código ese que agregaste puedes esplicarnos???

Comment: Quizás esto te sirva: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/327118/165037]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente tu profesor del curso lo que te pide es que pintes un array bidimensional y que por cada iteración en función de la posición y si el número del primer array verso al del segundo es par - impar / impar - par implementes una clase al elemento en cuestión.

Puesto que es un ejercicio tuyo, te indicaré cómo lo haría yo sin resolverte el ejercicio del todo, y si tienes dudas lo comentas por aquí.

```js
var br = document.createElement("br");      // Creamos los elementos que podemos fuera del loop para no sobrecargar el DOM
var section = document.querySelector('#tablero');

// El bucle iterará 8 veces (de 0 a 7), que son las filas que tiene un tablero de ajedrez, 
// y por cada iteración en una fila se efectuarán las iteración por columnas que este tiene (8)
for (var i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {  // Iteración por "fila"

    var fila = document.createElement("div"); // Para aplicar saltos de línea separamos las filas
    section.appendChild(fila);

    for (var j = 0; j <= 7; j++) { // La misma iteración pero pintando los cuadrados indivualmente

        var element = document.createElement("div");
        fila.appendChild(element);

        if (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 != 0 || i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 == 0) { // Aquí vemos si la relación fila-columna es par o impar, de esta manera implementaremos de manera alternada una clase para aplicarle por css un background distinto y hacer el efecto de tablero de ajedrez
            element.classList.add('oscuro');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#tablero {
    display: flex;
}

div {
    /* Todas las cuadrículas tienen el mismo ancho/alto/borde */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.oscuro {
    background-color: #c69b7c;
}
```

```html
<section id="tablero"></section>
```

Cabe destacar que es para que te hagas a la idea de cómo sería una de las **múltiples** formas de hacerlo.

Viendo que además tienes dos variables para recoger via `prompt()`los valores de ancho y alto de la cuadrícula, sólo tendrías que pasar esas variables a `i` y `j` respectivamente.

Por otro lado, si te piden que uses functiones y demás utilidades de Js, puedes sustituir y externalizar cosas como el loop, que pase por referencia por ejemplo de manera dinámica el iterador, usando un solo `for`. Pero mi recomendación si estás aprendiendo Javascript es que tengas claros lo conceptos básicos del lenguaje aplicables mediante algoritmia básica cómo este ejercicio, y después vayas escalando y cambiando el código con conceptos nuevos.

**EDITO:**
Si quisieras hacerlo un juego de ajedrez "real" podrías usar la librería `jquery-ui` utilizando el método `dragable()` para poder mover los elementos del con dicho método, pero te recomendaría asignar las posiciones de `a1` a `h8` para las casillas en un primer loop. Básicamente consistiría en crear objetos para cada tipo de pieza con identificadores para negras y blancas, y asignarle a cada uno de estos objetos clases comunas para cosas como la permisividad de movimiento, la posición inicial, o funciones especiales para los peones cómo la coronación, entre otras.